# C++ Reverse a null terminated string using the position of the terminator as swap space

Tags: c++, string, reverse

I'm working on the classic "Reverse a String" problem.

Is a good idea to use the position of the null terminator for swap space? The idea is to save the declaration of one variable.

Specifically, starting with Kernighan and Ritchie's algorithm:

```
void reverse(char s[])
{
    int length = strlen(s);
    int c, i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) 
    {
        c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = c;
    }
}
```

...can we instead do the following?

```
void reverseUsingNullPosition(char s[]) {
    int length = strlen(s);
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0, j = length - 1; i < j; i++, j--) {
        s[length] = s[i]; // Use last position instead of a new var
        s[i] = s[j];
        s[j] = s[length];
    }
    s[length] = 0; // Replace null character
}
```

Notice how the "c" variable is no longer needed. We simply use the last position in the array--where the null termination resides--as our swap space. When we're done, we simply replace the 0.

Here's the main routine (Xcode):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char cheese[] = { 'c' , 'h' , 'e' , 'd' , 'd' , 'a' , 'r' , 0 };
    printf("Cheese is: %s\n", cheese); //-> Cheese is: cheddar

    reverse(cheese);
    printf("Cheese is: %s\n", cheese); //-> Cheese is: raddehc

    reverseUsingNullPosition(cheese);
    printf("Cheese is: %s\n", cheese); //-> Cheese is: cheddar
}
```

Comment: Yes you can. Alas, just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: You can also do it with no temporary (using XORs). That also doesn't mean you should.

Comment: Care to explain? This method saves resources; specifically, the memory and overhead required for the variable named c

Comment: C++ already has a way to write swap without declaring an extra variable: `std::swap()`.

Comment: "method saves resources ...  overhead required for the variable named c" is true, yet code could get by with 2 pointers and a `char` instead.  That is less than `s,i,j,length`.  And in a larger sense, the savings per various methods are insignificant.

Comment: Does this routine form ***such** a bottleneck* in your application that saving **one byte** on the stack is worth the potential for breakage? The maintenance burden?

Comment: Note: Although reviewing code for efficients is good, all the examples do not _function_ well for _large_ strings as `size_t` should be used to index the array, not `int`.

Comment: No, not a good idea.  If the extra variable takes up any space on the stack at all (it might use a register instead), you get the space back when the function returns.

Comment: @Angnew, chux: Zero Overhead Principle, "...a language feature and a fundamental abstraction must be designed not to waste a single byte..." [Stroustrup, 2013, pp 10]

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this can be done. No, this is not a good idea, because it makes your program much harder to optimize.

When you declare `char c` in the local scope, the optimizer can figure out that the value is not used beyond the `s[j] = c;` assignment, and could place the temporary in a register. In addition to effectively eliminating the variable for you, the optimizer could even figure out that you are performing a swap, and emit a hardware-specific instruction. All this would save you a memory access per character.

When you use `s[length]` for your temporary, the optimizer does not have as much freedom. It is forced to emit the write into memory. This could be just as fast due to caching, but on embedded platforms this could have a significant effect.

Answer (score 5):

First of all **such microoptimizations are totally irrelevant until proven relevant**. We're talking about C++, you have `std::string`, `std::reverse`, you shouldn't even think about such facts.

In any case if you compile both code with -Os on Xcode you obtain for `reverse`:

```
.cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin0:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp3:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp4:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp5:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %r14
    pushq   %rbx
Ltmp6:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -32
Ltmp7:
    .cfi_offset %r14, -24
    movq    %rdi, %r14
Ltmp8:
    callq   _strlen
Ltmp9:
    leal    -1(%rax), %ecx
    testl   %ecx, %ecx
    jle LBB0_3
Ltmp10:
    movslq  %ecx, %rcx
    addl    $-2, %eax
Ltmp11:
    xorl    %edx, %edx
LBB0_2:
Ltmp12:
    movb    (%r14,%rdx), %sil
    movb    (%r14,%rcx), %bl
    movb    %bl, (%r14,%rdx)
    movb    %sil, (%r14,%rcx)
Ltmp13:
    incq    %rdx
    decq    %rcx
    cmpl    %eax, %edx
    leal    -1(%rax), %eax
    jl  LBB0_2
Ltmp14:
LBB0_3:
    popq    %rbx
    popq    %r14
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Ltmp15:
Lfunc_end0:
    .cfi_endproc
```

and for `reverseUsingNullPosition`:

```
    .cfi_startproc
Lfunc_begin1:
    pushq   %rbp
Ltmp19:
    .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
Ltmp20:
    .cfi_offset %rbp, -16
    movq    %rsp, %rbp
Ltmp21:
    .cfi_def_cfa_register %rbp
    pushq   %rbx
    pushq   %rax
Ltmp22:
    .cfi_offset %rbx, -24
    movq    %rdi, %rbx
Ltmp23:
    callq   _strlen
Ltmp24:
    leal    -1(%rax), %edx
    testl   %edx, %edx
Ltmp25:
    movslq  %eax, %rdi
    jle LBB1_3
Ltmp26:
    movslq  %edx, %rdx
    addl    $-2, %eax
Ltmp27:
    xorl    %esi, %esi
LBB1_2:
Ltmp28:
    movb    (%rbx,%rsi), %cl
    movb    %cl, (%rbx,%rdi)
    movb    (%rbx,%rdx), %cl
    movb    %cl, (%rbx,%rsi)
    movb    (%rbx,%rdi), %cl
    movb    %cl, (%rbx,%rdx)
Ltmp29:
    incq    %rsi
    decq    %rdx
    cmpl    %eax, %esi
    leal    -1(%rax), %eax
    jl  LBB1_2
Ltmp30:
LBB1_3:                                 ## %._crit_edge
    movb    $0, (%rbx,%rdi)
    addq    $8, %rsp
    popq    %rbx
Ltmp31:
    popq    %rbp
    ret
Ltmp32:
Lfunc_end1:
    .cfi_endproc
```

If you check the inner loop you have

```
movb    (%r14,%rdx), %sil
movb    (%r14,%rcx), %bl
movb    %bl, (%r14,%rdx)
movb    %sil, (%r14,%rcx)
```

vs

```
movb    (%rbx,%rsi), %cl
movb    %cl, (%rbx,%rdi)
movb    (%rbx,%rdx), %cl
movb    %cl, (%rbx,%rsi)
movb    (%rbx,%rdi), %cl
movb    %cl, (%rbx,%rdx)
```

So I wouldn't say you are saving so much overhead as you think (since you are accessing the array more times), maybe yes, maybe no. Which teaches you another thing: **thinking that some code is more performant than other code is irrelevant, the only thing that matters is a well-done benchmark and profile of the code**.

Answer (score 4):

Legal: Yes

Good idea: No

The cost of an "extra" variable is zero so there is absolutely no reason to avoid it. The stack pointer needs to be changed anyway so it doesn't matter if it needs to cope with an extra int.

Further:

With compiler optimization turned on, the variable c in the original code will most likely not even exists. It will just be a register in the cpu.

With your code: Optimization will be more difficult so it is not easy to say how well the compiler will do. Maybe you'll get the same - maybe you'll get something worse. But you won't get anything better.

So just forget the idea.

Answer (score 1):

We can use printf and the STL and also manually unroll things and use pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>

void reverse(char s[])
{
  char * b=s;
  char * e=s+::strlen(s)-4;

  while (e - b > 4)
  {
    std::swap(b[0], e[3]);
    std::swap(b[1], e[2]);
    std::swap(b[2], e[1]);
    std::swap(b[3], e[0]);
    b+=4;
    e-=4;
  }
  e+=3;

  while (b < e)
  {
    std::swap(*(b++), *(e--));
  }

}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char cheese[] = { 'c' , 'h' , 'e' , 'd' , 'd' , 'a' , 'r' , 0 };
    printf("Cheese is: %s\n", cheese); //-> Cheese is: cheddar

    reverse(cheese);
    printf("Cheese is: %s\n", cheese); //-> Cheese is: raddehc
}
```

Hard to tell if its faster with just the test case of "cheddar"